# Gas cost of Create2

Tags: gas, create2

I code a very simple program to test create2(). The program has two contracts, an empty firstContract, and a test contract to deploy firstContract via create2. The codes are below. Then I call deployContract() twice. First time costs ~10^5 gas. Second time costs ~10^9 gas. I know it is conflict of address since create2() returns the same address in the first time and the second time. But it doesn't report error and it costs much much more gas for the 2nd time than 1st time.

```
contract firstContract {}

contract test{

    address addr;

    function deployContract() external returns(address temp){

        bytes32 salt = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(addr));

        bytes memory bytecode = type(firstContract).creationCode;

        assembly {
            temp := create2(0, add(bytecode, 32), mload(bytecode), salt)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you run this multiple times and always got the same results?

Answer (score 0):

`CREATE2` has the same base-gas cost as `CREATE` (32000) but also an extra cost of hashing the initialization code. It is defined in [EIP-1014](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1014):

> `hashcost = GSHA3WORD * ceil(len(init_code) / 32)`

However, your problem seems to be that your second attempt is failing and therefore consuming all provided gas, here: apparently 1 billion. (I'm not sure where you would specify a 10^9 gas limit though.)